# How does paddling in the water help a boat move forward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

The way I've seen it explained is like this: it all has to do with Newton's third law. However, the "equal and opposite" reaction predicted by the third law acts on the paddle - which is not physically a part of the boat - and I can't find a good explanation that involves the boat itself.

Answer (score 2):

Well the paddle is physically part of the boat. The person holding the paddle is sitting in the boat making contact with it. If you were sitting say on friction-less raft (say with ice on its surface) you will propel yourself in the water and the raft will not move.